# Adding and using a console application to a windows form project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have a windows form application that picks a bunch of random numbers and then displays them. I have edited the 'Matrix Effect' console application to serve as a kind of animation for picking the numbers. I have added the console application to my random number picking project but how do I now use it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using textbox.text you have to get input as console.readline and to display some message you have to write console.writeline . This is simple thing which is different in console application otherwise everything else is same and logics also don't need to be changed :)

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    AllocConsole(); 
} 

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)] 
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] 
static extern bool AllocConsole();
```

I think so this should work if yes then please rate the answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been clear and I think you may have misunderstood. I actually want to run the console window after passing it some strings from my windows form application

Comment: using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AllocConsole();
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool AllocConsole(); I think so this should work if yes then please rate the answer :)

Comment: @HumzaMalik, add your comment to your answer, not as a comment and he may mark it as correct if it works.

Comment: @HumzaMalik I added the code you suggested, but this just opens a console window when the form is loaded. At a certain point in the code for my windows form application I need to pass some strings to a console application and the execute it.

Comment: @Luves2spooge Use the Console.WriteLine() to write into console.

Comment: @Luves2spooge please refer to this tutorial :) http://www.dotnetperls.com/main . Hope this will help and another way is you can make your own method for console window and then you can call that from you any other control to launch console window :)

Comment: how can I close that specific console once I've created it? I've tried `Environment.Exit(0)` but that shuts down my entire program.